# Is "by virtue of" neutral to the appended subject?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

AFAIK, "because of" is neutral to the appended subject, we could say "because of being good/bad".

But can I say "by virtue of being bad"? Is "by virtue of" neutral as well? Or it can only be used for good things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can say things like that. A real-life example from an author I personally really like:

> Invoked as threatening figures to control unruly children, or in bloody legends, moralistic ballads, and dark humor, such people are presented, **by virtue of their evil or demented actions**, as enemies of any social order and obvious criminals. (p 1120, *American Folklore: An Encyclopedia*, [Jan Harold Brunvand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jan_Harold_Brunvand), 1998)